# "Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast" warning isn't consistent across functions

Tags: c, pointers, arm, declaration, game-boy-advance

I'm using this header file to create two screen-related functions for the Game Boy Advance. The first function `ClearScreenWithColor` takes values for red, blue, and green and erases the bitmap screen with that color. The second is supposed to set or clear an undocumented display register that changes how the colors are displayed. Since these are memory-mapped ports, the data must be written to specific memory addresses. The variables `Screen` and `REG_GREENSWAP` stand in for the appropriate memory addresses. Here is the code below.

```
//SCREEN SETTINGS FUNCTIONS
#ifndef SCREENFUNC_H
#define SCREENFUNC_H

#define RGB16(r,g,b) ((r)+(g<<5)+(b<<10))
void ClearScreenWithColor(int red, int green, int blue)
// must be in screen mode 3 or this won't work.
{
    unsigned short* Screen = (unsigned short*)0x6000000;
    // define the pointer variable Screen to contain
    // the memory address 0x06000000.
    int color = RGB16(red,green,blue);
    char x,y;
    
    for (x = 0; x < 240; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < 160; y++)
        {
            Screen[x+y*240] = color;
        }
    }
}

void GreenSwap(short toggle)
{
    unsigned short* REG_GREENSWAP = (unsigned short*)0x04000002;
    
    REG_GREENSWAP = toggle;
}

#endif
```

When I compile the file, I get the following warning:

```
C:\gbaprog\gbaprint_test>gcc -S -o gbaprint_test.asm gbaprint_test.c
In file included from C:/gbaprog/lib/lib_header.h:9,
                 from gbaprint_test.c:19:
C:/gbaprog/lib/screenfunc.h: In function `GreenSwap':
C:/gbaprog/lib/screenfunc.h:28: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

That being said, the function `ClearScreenWithColor` doesn't produce this error message even though it uses the same syntax to assign the variable `Screen`. Why is the function `GreenSwap` different and what is different about my variable declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
REG_GREENSWAP = toggle;
```

`toggle` has type `short` while `REG_GREENSWAP` has type `short *`, so (as the error message says) you're assigning an integer value to a pointer without a cast.  This is also overwriting the value that `REG_GREENSWAP` was initialized with.

Presumably, what you actually want to do is to dereference `REG_GREENSWAP` and write to the memory location it points to.

```
*REG_GREENSWAP = toggle;
```

There's no error with `Screen[x+y*240] = color;` because array indexing implicitly dereferneces a pointer.

On a side note, it's not a good idea to have a function's implementation in a header file.  If that header is included in more that one source file, the function will be defined in each object file and when you attempt to link them you'll get a multiple definition error.

The header should only include *declarations* for your functions while the implementation should be in exactly one source file.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that array indexing used pointers. That explains why Screen had no issue. I'll keep that side note in mind. I'm used to assembly where function declaration and definition are one and the same.

Comment: @puppydrum64 Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: I would if I knew how. But there's another problem. Moving those functions to the main file and just declaring them in the included file led to a whole bunch of compiler errors. I can't list them all here, but I don't get those errors if I either leave my code as is, or take everything out of the header file and put it in the main file.

Comment: @puppydrum64 To accept an answer, click the green checkmark to the left of the answer you want to accept.  As for the the other errors, create a separate post for that.

Comment: @puppydrum64 And as a general rule, when dealing with compiler errors start from the top down.  Oftentimes correcting one will make several others downstream disappear.

Comment: I've noticed it's often something as simple as forgetting a semicolon in line 1 and it throws everything off. (I've been spoiled by VASM- it tells me exactly what I did wrong 99% of the time.)